# react native overlay permission

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As I run my react native app, the emulator displays an overlay
   'permission is required' in order to run app in dev mode. As per my
   research I added the

```
 <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
```

line of code in `AndroidManifest.xml` file, but still it displays the
   same message. I also tried with the removing this line of code from
   `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Comment: the odds to get this answered would certainly be much better if you could add the exact text of the error message, and the line of code you used in the manifest.

Comment: Most probably it's not the app itself but a third party you've implemented that uses overlay, by default React-Native doesn't require overlay permission, check your third parties